# Capture last value of an observable with multiple requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service layer responsible for handling the data and sending it to components that use the same value.

I need to make requests to the api, as long as the value is `isProcessed == false` it will do 10 attempts every half a second.

If it fails during the attempts, it will only make 3 more requests.

If `isProcessed == true`, stopped the requisitions.

All the logic is built in, but I can't output the last observable value. All responses are sent.

All requests are sent by observables, both false and true, but I only need the last one.

[image]

**Here all requests responses are arriving in the component, not just the last**

Service responsible for accessing API:

```
public getPositionConsolidate(): Observable<PosicaoConsolidada> {       
    return this.http.get<PosicaoConsolidada>(`${environment.api.basePosicaoConsolidada}/consolidado`)
      .pipe(
        map(res => res),
        retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()),
        shareReplay(1),
        catchError(err => {
            console.log('Error in Position Consolidate', err);
            return throwError(err);
        })
    )
}
```

Service responsible for handling the data and sending it to the component:

```
public positionConsolidate() {
    let subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    this.api.getPositionConsolidate().subscribe(response => {
        if(response.hasProcessado == false) {
            for (let numberRequest = 0; numberRequest < 10; numberRequest++) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                   //subject.next(this.api.getPosicaoConsolidada().subscribe());
                   this.api.getPositionConsolidate().subscribe(res => {
                        subject.next(res)
                   })
                }, numberRequest * 500, numberRequest);
            }
        } else {
            retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()),
            finalize(() => this.loadingService.loadingOff())
        }   
    })
    return subject.asObservable()
}
```

In component:

```
public ngOnInit() {
 this.coreState.positionConsolidate().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: [last()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest part to answer of your question, is that if you just want the last emission from an observable, then just use the **last** operator.  However, the way you've written things, makes it difficult to incorperate.  The following refactors your code as a single stream without any non-rxjs control structures.

```
public positionConsolidate() {

  return this.api.getPositionConsolidate().pipe(
    concatMap(res => iif(() => res.hasProcessado,
      of(res),
      interval(500).pipe(
        take(10),
        concatMap(() => this.api.getPositionConsolidate())
      )
    )),
    retryWhen(genericRetryStrategy()),
    finalize(() => this.loadingService.loadingOff()),
    last()
  );
}
```

**What's happening**

- First this executes the initial api call.
- Then based on the result, either...

  - Returns the initial result
  - Calls the api 10 times every 500ms.
- Implements what you have for **retryWhen** and **finalize**.
- Returns the last emitted result.

Also don't subscribe to observables inside of observables - that's what higher order observables such as *concatMap* are for.

Comment: could take a look at this question, it's related to your answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383006/validation-of-an-observable-response-before-registration-to-perform-multiple-req