# Validation of an observable response before registration to perform multiple requests(iff) - RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a method that makes requests to the server while the field hasProcessado (hasProcessed in english) is false, if it is true, it should stop making new requests. A maximum of 10 requests are made, in case of error it makes only 3 requests.

**But in server, even when `hasProcessado == true` it keeps making requests. Doing local tests works normally**

```
public pullingPerfilInvestor(): Observable<any> {
    let result = this.http.get<PerfilInvestor>(this.configService.generateNewUrl(`${environment.api.endpoints.obterPerfil}`), { headers: this.configService.concatenateHeaders(true) })
    return result
      .pipe(
        concatMap(res => iif(() => res.hasProcessado,
          of(res),
          interval(500).pipe(
            take(9),
            concatMap(() => result)
          )
        )),
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            delayWhen(val => timer(500)),
            concatMap((error, index) => {
              if (index === 2) {
                return throwError(error)
              }
              return of(null);
            }),
            take(3)
          )
        ),
        shareReplay(1),
        last()
      );
  }
```

My Object in SoapUi:

```
{
    "perfil": {
        "hasPerfil": true,
        "descricao": "Arrojado",
        "aderencia": {
            "exibirMensagem": true}
        },
    "questionario": {
        "vencimento": "01.12.2021",
        "isVencido": false
        },
        "hasProcessado": false
}
```

In my browser local, makes the 10 requests because in soapUi the `hasProcessado == false:`

[image]

While hasProcessed is false:

[image]

**After hasProcessado is true, it keeps making requests**

[image]

My object in server:

```
{
   "hasProcessado":true,
   "dataPosicao":null,
   "perfil":{
      "hasPerfil":true,
      "descricao":"Arrojado",
      "aderencia":{
         "isExibirMensagem":false
      }
   },
   "questionario":{
      "vencimento":"15.06.2022",
      "isVencido":false
   }
}
```

*OBS: I believe it's something with concatMap and iff.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `take` operator the wrong way.
The code below is great but works the way you need it:

- Performs pulling conditionally on the result of the request;
- Performs 3 more pullings if the request is successful

  ```
    public pullingPerfilInvestor() {
        let countTimes = 0;

    interval(500)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(() => this.http.get<PerfilInvestidor>(this.configService.gerarUrlNovo(`${environment.api.endpointsNovos.obterPerfil}`), { headers: this.configService.concatenarHeaders(true) })),
        filter((data: PerfilInvestidor) => {
          countTimes = countTimes + 1;
          return data.hasProcessado === true || countTimes == this.MAX_PULLING;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            delayWhen(val => timer(500)),
            concatMap((error, index) => {
              if (index === 2) {
                return throwError(error)
              }
              return of(null);
            }),
            take(3)
          )
        ),
        take(1),
        shareReplay(1),
        last()
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.perfilSubject.next(response)
      }, error => {
        this.perfilSubject.error(error);
      });
  }
  ```